# Firebase AuthUI - Find if existing user or new user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making use of firebase AuthUI to signup/login users. Depending on if the user is new or an existng user I need to redirect them to different view controllers. Does firebase provide a function to check that?

Here is my current code that, irrespective of new or registered user, segues to 'signUpSegue'

```
@IBAction func phoneNumberLoginAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.delegate = self as FUIAuthDelegate
    let phoneProvider = FUIPhoneAuth.init(authUI: FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!)
    FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.providers = [phoneProvider]
    // 1
    print("clicked butto")
    guard let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        else { return }

    // 2
    authUI.delegate = self as FUIAuthDelegate

    // 3
    let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
    present(authViewController, animated: true)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension WelcomeViewController: WelcomePageViewControllerDelegate, FUIAuthDelegate {
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
    print("handle user signup / login")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpSegue", sender: nil)
}

func welcomePageViewController(_ welcomePageViewController: WelcomePageViewController,
                                didUpdatePageCount count: Int) {
    pageControl.numberOfPages = count
}

func welcomePageViewController(_ welcomePageViewController: WelcomePageViewController,
                                didUpdatePageIndex index: Int) {
    pageControl.currentPage = index
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saving the user to the database under a "Users" node, with their Auth ID? If you are, just do a query with the returned UID to see if they exist like this...

```
func checkIfUserExistsAlready(_ uid: String, complete: @escaping ((_ doesExist: Bool) -> Void)) {

 //userRef if a Database Reference to "Users" node

        userRef.child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                complete(true)
            } else {
                complete(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

You can call this and check in the FUIAuthDelegate function

```
 func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {

    //Call does exists function here with user.uid

    //Have if statement here and perform segues accordingly

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "signUpSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is not documented, but there is a callback function `didSignInWithAuthDataResult` which returns an [`AuthDataResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuthDataResult) which provides a way to tell if a user is new or existing via `additionalUserInfo.newUser`.

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/a69aa9536a0f5312bdd2d408a761c7dd21698015/FirebaseAuthUI/FUIAuth.h#L54

Answer (score 0):

a) Try log in the Firebase whit the the phone number.
b) If the Firebase return error, check the error?.localizedDescription
c) If the error is an inexistent user, your user is new.
d) If the error is a wrong password, try a different password.